# Facebook Graph API: unable to get shared posts although share count is higher than zero

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm experiencing a weird behavior from the graph API: i want to list shares of a shared posts, so i'm requesting `/<post_id>/sharedposts?fields=shares` to get the number of times a shared posts has been subsequentially shared.

The response i'm getting, thus, is a list of objects like this:

```
{
  "shares": {
    "count": 1
  },
  "id": "136178893505927_155012298289253"
},
```

However, if i request `/136178893505927_155012298289253/sharedposts`, I get

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Which is weird, as I was expecting one  object to be in the response.

Moreover, if I request `/<post_id>/sharedposts?fields=shares,sharedposts` i'm getting a weird list containing `shares.count` higher than 0 and no `sharedposts` content in some cases and a `sharedposts` array containing less elements than `shares.count` in some others.

I'm guessing this happens because the shared posts are not visible to my profile, but shouldn't I be able to see them, since the original post was published on a page I manage?

I'm trying to build the graph of shares to determine if a share being re-shared contributed more than others to the overall share count, but it looks like this is not feasible with the graph API...or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Use Graph api v2.3 and you need read_stream permission.
This permission is only in this version.